# error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application while making node.js library in c++

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I built node in Visual Studio and then by setting the appropriate paths in Visual Studio project compile this code in .node extension successfully.

```
#include <node.h>

namespace demo {

    using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
    using v8::Isolate;
    using v8::Local;
    using v8::Object;
    using v8::String;
    using v8::Value;

    void Method(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
        Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
        args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "world"));
    }

    void init(Local<Object> exports) {
        NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "hello", Method);
    }

    NODE_MODULE(addon, init)

}
```

But when I am calling this module through this code,

```
var addon = require('./nodeExt');

console.log(addon.hello());
```

I am getting the above error. please give your suggestions.

Comment: *How* do you build your extension? What project-type is it?

Comment: i build it in visual studio and make the extension .node

Comment: Did you create a *windows exe project*, a *windows console project*, a *dll procject*? Something else? Statically or dynamically linked?

Comment: i selected dll project

Answer (score 0):

Building in Visual Studio and changing the extension to .node won't work. You need to use node-gyp to configure and build native addons for node.js. See the guide here:

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/addons.html

Tip: After you run `node-gyp configure`, you can then open the .sln file (build/Release/binding.sln or build/Debug/binding.sln) with Visual Studio.